# Rails how is rendering process carried out?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rendering

Let's assume that we have an `.html.erb` file which contains 20 LOC. The file also takes a variable to display relevant data.

I want to know if the file is locally accessible to the user and the client browser does the rendering process of combining the data with the `erb` file(which means that the `erb` file is already available to the client and the server only needs to transfer data: less overhead) **OR**
the server combines the data with the `erb` file and then transfers it(more overhead).

I'm not considering AJAX calls in the above example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Embedded Ruby (ERB)](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/reference/lang_template_erb.html) is a server side templating language.

Since the `/app` folder resides outside the Rails servers web root (`/public`) the user should not have any direct access to views.

Like all classical server side rendering the client merely sends requests and the server renders the templates completely and sends "finished" html* to the client. This is no different than PHP for example.

You can use Rails with other server side templating languages (Slim, Haml, jBuilder etc.).

You can also use client side templating languages like Handlebars, Mustache, Jade, EJS, JSX and simply deliver JSON data from your rails app.

Comment: There is no ERB client side implementation (of notice) at the moment. This is because ERB is tightly tied to the Ruby language. In the future when NaCL is a realistic option it could become a viable idea.

Comment: * ERB can render other text formats such as JSON, YAML, JS, XML, Markdown, plaintext etc.

Comment: Thank you! Just the explanation I needed. Thanks for also pointing out the client side alternatives. May I know which one do you prefer with rails to display repetitive data like comments or notifications on SO?